# Select column value based on other row values

Tags: sql

I tried for hours and read many posts but I still can't figure out how to handle this request:

I have a table like this :

| Gender | Marks |
| --- | --- |
| M | 75 |
| F | 88 |
| M | 93 |
| M | 88 |
| F | 98 |

I'd like to select all boys from the table and set the sameMarks column to 1 when the boy marks match the girl marks, otherwise it should be 0.
The output should look like this:

| Gender | Marks | Same_Marks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| M | 75 | 0 |
| M | 93 | 0 |
| M | 88 | 1 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is using `EXISTS` to check if women with the same mark exist and applying a `CASE WHEN` on the result:

```
SELECT 
y.gender, y.marks,
CASE WHEN 
  EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM yourtable WHERE gender <> 'M' and marks = y.marks) 
  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Same_Marks
FROM yourtable y
WHERE y.gender = 'M';
```

Note: This answer assumes you really want to get boys only, no women (according to your description). If this is incorrect, please review and improve your question.

Like Tim already mentioned, it would be much better to use 'B' for both genders.

Comment: I think it is coincidental that there are no women-only marks, rather than it being a requirement to not report such records.

Comment: Jonas thanks for your help this is what I was looking for.
I have also modified the question so that someone else will not have difficulty in understanding it now

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach would be aggregation:

```sql
SELECT MAX(Gender) AS Gender,
       Marks,
       CASE WHEN MIN(Gender) = MAX(Gender) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Same_Marks
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Marks;
```

Comment: This will also fetch women if they appear without a boy having the same mark. This seems to be not intended ("I'd like to select all boys") although the description is not 100% clear.

Comment: The problem is with the male gender output for marks = 88.  Rightfully, there should be something like `B` as output (for both), as both genders are present.

Comment: Yes, agree this would be much cleaner!